# Using whereIn() method with laravel Eloquent Model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So I have a laravel app which contains a host of different models and some are dependent on another. In standard SQL you would use a simple join statement and be done with it. However, Laravels Eloquent Models offers functions to build these relationships easily (i.e hasOne,hasMany etc). So I defined my relationships with the latter method and have actually used them successfully.

In attempt to using the Eloquent model along with its defined  relationships here:

```
 vehicle::with(['colors:id,Color', 'damages:id,Damage','secondaryDamages:id,Damage',
'modeldetails.model','modeldetails.engine_type',
'modeldetails.fuel_type','modeldetails.transmission_type',
'modeldetails.body_type','modeldetails.drive_type, 'modeldetails.model.vendor','auctionday']);
```

But the problem arises when I attempt to chain this command with 
`whereIn()`.

```
     vehicle::with(['colors:id,Color', 'damages:id,Damage','secondaryDamages:id,Damage',
    'modeldetails.model','modeldetails.engine_type',
    'modeldetails.fuel_type','modeldetails.transmission_type',
    'modeldetails.body_type','modeldetails.drive_type, 'modeldetails.model.vendor','auctionday'])
->whereIn([id, $arrayofValuetoMatch]);
```

See querying "id" for the table works fine, it is when I would query for other columns belong to other tables like **'modeldetails.model.vendor.id' which would cause an **error** for Unknown column.**if it was in place of id in the `whereIn()`

So my question is how would I name the column parameter in a `whereIn()` method while using laravels eloquent relationships. Or do I need to use the join method to have access to these columns?

Here is the original error

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'vehicle_makes.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `vehicles` where `vehicle_makes`.`id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)).

"vehicle_makes" is the original table name but it doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Are you sure you are using `withIn()` not `whereIn()` ? I haven't seen `withIn()` method in laravel

Comment: Sorry was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I assume from your question that you want to use filter on related models that are associated with your model you could use `whereHas()` for this purpose

```
$vendorIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$vehicles= vehicle::with([....])
                  ->whereHas('modeldetails.model.vendor', function ($query) use ($vendorIds) {
                        $query->whereIn('id',$vendorIds);
                  })->get();
```

Also see section [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Works perfectly thanks, but being that it is bad habit to not fully understanding the code you are using, can you explain the second param for <code>whereHas()</code>. I have never seen the use of  "use" with a function ever. Is this laravel specific?

Comment: @CalixteSimeon Its not a complex thing nor related to laravel its just a closure function, means `whereHas` accepts a callback function, To pass additional parameters to closure function  you need "use" keyword have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php for more clarification